# Android Studio running Android (Java) Project as Flutter Project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

### Situation and Problem

I have been working with Android Projects using android studio for a while in Java. Recently, I have started learning Flutter and therefore added Flutter modules into Android Studio.

I opened both Android Project and Flutter Project at the same time in different windows and both project can share the same emulator, and everything seemed to work fine. Yet, the next day I opened the Android Project again, the WHOLE IDE was configured with Flutter settings. This means that:
1. Android Project is NOT synced with gradle, and thus all the imports failed marked red
2. All gradle related files are not visible in the project folder in Android Studio (still exists in folder)
3. All gradle operations are gone because the IDE is configured for Flutter. So there is no rebuild project/clean project/ sync with gradle files button

### Things I have tried

1. Reopen the project
2. Invalidate cache and restart
3. Restart PC

But none of them seemed to work. If I tried to create a new Android Project, the new Android Project seems to work fine with all gradle operations available.

### Android Studio Versions

Android Studio 3.4
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1343-b01 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

I tried to look for similar issues but none seems to match this one. Any one can help?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Yesterday, I updated Android Studio to 3.6.1 and that fixed it. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the workaround solution is to import the project again instead of opening the project.

When importing, remember to choose opening it as an Android Gradle Project.